# random effect with high variability in record numbers per factor level

Tags: mixed-model, independence, observational-study

I'm dealing with a large observational data set, where I have yield values (response variable) nested within farm and location. When farm and location are included in a random intercept model, both are significant when evaluated with likelihood ratio tests (method from Zuur et al 2009).

There several issues. One is that my "farm" effect has many factor levels (>1000, with n= 3500), which makes it very computationally expensive to include in a model. The second issue which I am very unclear about is that nearly half of "farm" factor levels only have a single yield value associated with them. The other half of "farm" factor levels have between 2-50 yield values associated with them.

A significant pool of my data will be lost if I exclude farms with only one associated yield value, and yield values associated with a single farm are clearly related to one another (therefore cannot be viewed as independent).

What I need help understanding is:

1) Why is it a bad idea to include a random effect with many factor levels and only one record associated with some of the factor levels

2) This one might be a little subjective, but are the answers to number 1 worse than assuming independence of non-independent observations by not including the random effect?

Let me know if this question would benefit from including data/code.

Comment: This question could surely benefit from including data (maybe a link to download it) and some code!